# why do I get the man pages error and how to fix it in fedora core 19?

Tags: linux, fedora, manpage

```
$ man 2 listen
No manual entry for listen in section 2
```

How can I fix it? What is the issue here?
I am using FC19.

Comment: Is this Fedora 16 or 19?

Comment: Why is the question tagged with Fedora 16, then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have installed "man-pages" rpm package? Seems you have no file /usr/share/man/man2/listen.2.gz - you have to install it with "yum install man-page" or "rpm -i man-page*"

Comment: By the way, Why by default the entire man package is not installed?

Comment: When I install Fedora I always choose individual package installation and set installing man pages. Maybe you choosed minimal installation or something like that and there is no man pages?